# Can I say $Y-$axis is a tangent to $f(x)$ at origin?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

$f(x) = x^2$ when $x \geq 0$

I think any line passing through origin is a tangent to $f(x)$ at the origin.

Please do not close the question.

Can anyone answer me ?

Comment: It depends on your definition of tangent.

Comment: There is for example such definition: tangent to $f(x)$ at $x=a$ is line $y=kx+b$ such that $\lim_{x\to a} {f(x)-(kx+b)}{x}=0$. For this definition there is only one tangent line for your example.

Comment: Another possible definition: $\lim_{x\to a} \frac{l_2}{l_1}=0$, where $l_2$ is distance from curve point to tangent line, $l_1$ is distance from curve point to curve point at $x=a$. This definition allows vertical tangent lines.

Answer (score 0):

A function is differentiable on $a$ if and only if the tangent line to its graph is defined in $a$.
As $f(x)=x^2$ is differentiable at $0$, the tangent line to the graph of $f$ is defined at $x=0$, which has equation $y=0$, since $(0 ,0)\in G_f$ and $f'(0)=2\times 0=0$.
The most common definition for a tangent line is:

A tangent line to the function $f(x)$ at the point $x=a$
is a line that just touches the graph of the function at the point in question and is “parallel” (in some way) to the graph at that point.

I like to think that a line divides the plane into two subplanes and if a line is tangent to the graph of a function, then in a neighborhood of that point, there can only be points on the graph of that function in one of the half-planes.

So, let's take the line $y=x$. It is clear that this line divides the plane into the half-planes $y<0$ and $y\geqslant0$, and in an arbitrary neighborhood of $f$ there are points on the graph of $f$ in the two half-planes, which contradicts \textbf{my } definition of tangency.

**NOTE**

There are tangent lines that intersect the graph infinite times, just take
$f(x)=x^2\sin(\frac1x) \,\text{if}\, x\ne0$ and $f(0)=0$ and the points of the form $(\frac1{n\pi},0)$, $n \in\mathbb Z\backslash\{0\}$.